# Why is Rails 6 Stimulus Reflex re-rendering the page with duplicate content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, actioncable, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

I have been working on getting Stimulus Reflex up and running in an existing Rails 6 app.  Success!  I have a couple reflexes in action, ActionCable is doing its job...all good.  However, after the reflex is successful and Stimulus communicates via ActionCable, the page updates before my eyes with duplicate content.

The form below simply hits a reflex that saves the form object.  As you can see, the page is not correct after Stimulus and or Turbolinks re-renders the form.  In this case, it double renders the form submit button.

I can't figure out why this is occurring and hoping somebody here has seen this double render issue.

## before

[image]

## after

[image]

## the HTML

```
    <%= block_card title: 'BILLING', footer: (link_to('Add Billing Detail', new_project_billing_detail_path(@project)) if policy(@project.billing_details.new).new?) do %>
      <%= @alert %>
        <%= form_with model: @billing_detail, html: { novalidate: true }, data: { reflex: "submit->BillingDetailReflex#submit" } do |form| %>
          <% if @billing_detail.errors.any? %>
            <% @billing_detail.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <%= tag.li message %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <div>
            <%= form.text_field :date, 
              placeholer: 'Date',
              required: true,
              data: { reflex: "change->BillingDetailReflex#submit" } %>

            <%= form.text_field :billing_code, 
              placeholer: 'Billing Code',
              required: true,
              data: { reflex: "change->BillingDetailReflex#submit" } %>

            <%= form.text_field :project_id %>
            <%= form.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
          </div>          
          <%= form.submit %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

## the Reflex

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class BillingDetailReflex < ApplicationReflex
  before_reflex do
    @billing_detail = BillingDetail.new
    @billing_detail.assign_attributes(billing_detail_params)
  end

  def submit
    if @billing_detail.save!
      @alert = "saved id:#{ @billing_detail&.id }"
    else
      @alert = 'NOT saved'
    end
  end

  private

  def billing_detail_params
    params.require(:billing_detail).permit(
      :date,
      :billing_cycle,
      :user_id,
      :project_id
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be related to the "block_card" helper method.  All that method does is wrap the block in a bootstrap card div.  I'll repost here as I figure out why this helper is throwing off Stimulus/turbolinks.

Comment: This is apparently a Turbolinks thing

Answer (score 4):

It seems StimulusReflex was unable to successfully identify the existing form element when updating the page with the new content. Try adding a unique id to the form element.

Also, StimulusReflex will emit JavaScript console messages to help you debug, but this needs to be explicitly enabled. SEE: https://docs.stimulusreflex.com/troubleshooting#logging

Please join us in Discord where you'll find lots of helpful hands. https://discord.gg/xFqhV5